# How to maintain counters with LinqToObjects?

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have the following c# code:

```
    private XElement BuildXmlBlob(string id, Part part, out int counter)
    {
        // return some unique xml particular to the parameters passed
        // remember to increment the counter also before returning.
    }
```

Which is called by:

```
        var counter = 0;
        result.AddRange(from rec in listOfRecordings
                        from par in rec.Parts
                        let id = GetId("mods", rec.CKey + par.UniqueId)
                        select BuildXmlBlob(id, par, counter));
```

*Above code samples are symbolic of what I am trying to achieve.*

According to the Eric Lippert, the out keyword and linq does not mix. OK fair enough but can someone help me refactor the above so it does work? A colleague at work mentioned accumulator and aggregate functions but I am novice to Linq and my google searches were bearing any real fruit so I thought I would ask here :).

**To Clarify:**

I am counting the number of parts I might have which could be any number of them each time the code is called. So every time the BuildXmlBlob() method is called, the resulting xml produced will have a unique element in there denoting the 'partNumber'.

So if the counter is currently on 7, that means we are processing 7th part so far!! That means XML returned from BuildXmlBlob() will have the counter value embedded in there somewhere. That's why I need it somehow to be passed and incremented every time the BuildXmlBlob() is called per run through.

Comment: Why do you even need that counter? What are you counting? If you want a count of the items in the query, just `Count()` it.

Comment: That might not work- :). I am counting the number of parts I might have which could be any number of them each time the code is called.

Comment: Is the counter value being used within `BuildXmlBlob()`? If so, using `out` is very misleading. If anything, it should be a `ref` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep this purely in LINQ and you need to maintain a running count for use within your queries, the cleanest way to do so would be to make use of the `Select()` overloads that includes the index in the query to get the current index.

In this case, it would be cleaner to do a query which collects the inputs first, then use the overload to do the projection.

```
var inputs =
    from recording in listOfRecordings
    from part in recording.Parts
    select new
    {
        Id = GetId("mods", recording.CKey + part.UniqueId),
        Part = part,
    };
result.AddRange(inputs.Select((x, i) => BuildXmlBlob(x.Id, x.Part, i)));
```

Then you wouldn't need to use the `out`/`ref` parameter.

```
XElement BuildXmlBlob(string id, Part part, int counter)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I managed to figure out on my own:.

```
            result.AddRange(listOfRecordings.SelectMany(rec => rec.Parts, (rec, par) => new {rec, par})
                            .Select(@t => new
                                {
                                    @t, 
                                    Id = GetStructMapItemId("mods", @t.rec.CKey + @t.par.UniqueId)
                                })
                            .Select((@t, i) => BuildPartsDmdSec(@t.Id, @t.@t.par, i)));
```

I used resharper to convert it into a method chain which constructed the basics for what I needed and then i simply tacked on the select statement right at the end.